# Program isn't printing first digits of two strings

Tags: char, user-input

Hi I'm learning C through the Modern Approach book. For this program, we just need to input a first name and last name, and the program should return Last Name, First Initial.

```
char *first [255];
 char *last [255];
 printf("Enter a first name and a last name: ");
 while (getchar() == ' ');
 scanf("%s", first);
 while (getchar() == ' ');
scanf("%s", last);
 while (getchar() == ' ');

 char firstInitial = (char) first[0];
 printf("%s, ", last);
 putchar(firstInitial);
```

When I run it, it doesn't print the first two characters.

e.g
Enter a first name and a last name: Aaron Smith
mith, a

Answer (score 0):

This will get you started with getting the the first name.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  // Create a string
  char firstName[255];

  // Ask the user to input some text
  printf("Enter your first name: \n");

  // Get and save the text
  scanf("%s", firstName);

  // Output the text
  printf("first name %s.  1st char %c", firstName, firstName[0]);
  
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h> 
void main() 
{ 
 char a = getchar(); 
 char b; 
 scanf("%c",&b); 
 printf("%c",b); 
}
```

Run the above code and see the result for yourself.

you can see that the getchar() function terminates only after when a “enter” key is pressed.

this causes an additional ‘\n’ character along with the single character you entered, to be in the input queue.

so character ‘b’ is assigned ‘\n’ and the compiler does not prompt you to provide input for ‘b’.